# Query executing multiple times when using google social login with passport and sequelize

Tags: node.js, passport.js, sequelize.js

Hi Guys this is my first question so please be patient, I'm having a problem using passport with sequelize, the problem happens after i search at the database for the record to check if the user already exists but when passport deserializes it, Sequelize executes five 'select queries', the code is similar to one i found in scotch.io i just attached sequelize api to it:

```
module.exports = function (passport) {

    // used to serialize the user for the session
    passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        done(null, user.iduser);
    });

    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
        userModel.findById(id)
        .then(function (userVo) {
            done(null, userVo);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            if(err)
                throw err;
        })
    });

    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
            clientID: 'XXXXX',
            clientSecret: 'XXXXXX',
            callbackURL: 'XXXXX'
        },
        function (token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            // make the code asynchronous
            // User.findOne won't fire until we have all our data back from Google
            process.nextTick(function () {
                // try to find the user based on their google id
                sequelize.transaction(function (t) {
                        return sociaLoginModel.findOne({
                                where: {
                                    idprovided: profile.id,
                                    logintype: constants.GOOGLE_LOGIN_TYPE
                                }
                            }, {
                                transaction: t
                            })
                            .then(function (socialLoginResult) {
                                //if user was found, then retrieve and create a session for him returning the value to done
                                var socialLoginVo;
                                if (socialLoginResult) {
                                    socialLoginVo = socialLoginResult.dataValues
                                    return userModel.findById(socialLoginVo.tb11_fkuser, {
                                            transaction: t
                                        })
                                        .then(function (userResult) {
                                            return userResult.dataValues;
                                        });
                                } else {
                                    return individualsModel.create({
                                            name: profile.displayName
                                        }, {
                                            transaction: t
                                        })
                                        .then(function (individualsResult) {
                                            var individualsVo = individualsResult.dataValues
                                            return userModel.create({
                                                    email: profile.emails[0].value,
                                                    user_type: constants.USER_INDIVIDUALS,
                                                    tb12_fkindividuals: individualsVo.idindividuals
                                                }, {
                                                    transaction: t
                                                })
                                                .catch(function (err) {
                                                    if (err)
                                                        throw err;
                                                })
                                                .then(function (userResult) {
                                                    var userVo = userResult.dataValues
                                                    console.log(typeof profile.id)
                                                    return sociaLoginModel.create({
                                                            idprovided: profile.id,
                                                            token: token,
                                                            logintype: constants.GOOGLE_LOGIN_TYPE,
                                                            tb11_fkuser: userVo.iduser
                                                        }, {
                                                            transaction: t
                                                        })
                                                        .then(function (sociaLoginResult) {
                                                            return userVo
                                                        })
                                                        .catch(function(err) {
                                                            if(err)
                                                                throw err;
                                                        })
                                                })
                                        }).catch(function(err) {
                                            if(err)
                                                throw err
                                        })
                                }
                            }).catch(function(err) {
                                if(err)
                                    throw err
                            })
                    }).then(function (result) {
                        return done(null, result);
                    }).catch(function (err) {
                        if (err) 
                            return done(err)
                    });
            })
        }))
};
```

This code is in a file and i use it as a middleware in app.js calling:

```
require('./logins/google')(passport);
```

I do that with local-login and facebook too, as almost the same code as in google login, why does Sequelize is executing that number of queries?? Am i doing something wrong?? How can i minimize that number? Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that _all_ of your frontend requests (CSS, JS, favicon.ico) are causing `passport.deserializeUser()` to be called.

Comment: My route that does this request is the '/', the only thing i do is verify req.isAutenticated() if is, then render index with the user email, if not, only render without setting attributes to the page. But this counts as only one query to deserialize the user isn't it?

Comment: It depends on your page. Are you using `express.static()`, for instance?

Comment: Yes, it's declared like this:
`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`
I'm new at nodejs and javascript, i don't know exactly what it does, it just got there cause i generated it from express-generator

Comment: The number of requests may drop when you move the `express.static()` middleware _before_ `app.use(passport.initialize())`.

Comment: @robertklep it worked!! Could you explain me why??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your comments I inferred that your Express/Passport setup looked somewhat similar to this:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(express.static(...));
```

Because Express calls middleware in order, this means that each request will first be passed through the Passport middleware before it reaches the static middleware.

The Passport middleware calls `passport.deserializeUser(...)`, so it will also be called for the requests that will eventually be handled by the static middleware (for instance, CSS/JS/HTML files).

If you rearrange the middleware order, the static middleware will be called first for those particular requests, and only if it cannot handle the request (for instance, for a request that should be handled by one of your routes) will it pass the request along to the Passport middleware:

```
app.use(express.static(...));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: It just worked perfectly for me, i didn't have a clue about that problem, thanks @robertklep

Comment: It took care of extra calls but I got this error: Unhandled rejection Error: passport.initialize() middleware not in use

Comment: @iMad perhaps open a new question for that, including your Express setup.